# Meaning of the phrase 'luck of late'

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

I came across the phrase *luck of late* in the short story [The Thief](https://short-storylovers.blogspot.com/2012/07/thief-by-ruskin-bond.html?m=1#:%7E:text=I%C2%A0hadn%E2%80%99t%20%C2%A0had%20much%20luck%20of%20late) by Ruskin Bond(Para 2 Line 2):

> > I approached him. He was about twenty, a tall, lean fellow, and he looked kind and simple enough for my purpose. I hadn’t had much *luck of late* and thought I might be able to get into this young person’s confidence.

I'm unable to comprehend its meaning nor can I look it up.

I wonder if it simply means the narrator approached him without any delay or something else.

Comment: The phrase is not _luck of late_, but _of late_ meaning _recently_. The narrator had been going through a period of bad luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You weren't able to look it up because it isn't one single phrase, but two:

**I hadn't had much [luck](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/luck)**: my luck had been bad
[**of late**](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/of--late): recently